# cleartool list activities since last 7 days

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

We use ClearCase UCM which has multiple Vobs (10).

How to find the activities for past one week?
Or list activities between two date ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit trickey, because all [`cleartool lsactivity`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsactivity.htm) commands are limited to one pvob ("project vob" or "special vob with UCM metadata in it"):

```
cleartool lsact -invob \my\pvob -stream ...
```

And an activity can be reused (meaning an old activity can have in its changeset very recent versions)

If you have two baselines, you can easily diff them (by activity):  See ..[`diffbl`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm)**.

```
ct diffbl -act baseline:bas1@\myPVob baseline:bas2@\myPVob
```

(that is necessary for one component within one Vob though)

But if not, you need to list all activities and their changeset, to see which one contains version produced in the relevant date range.

Answer (score 2):

We are using a ClearCase UCM plugin which called "Compare BL", made by "Go Midjets". It answers your needs.

Comment: It is now called "R&D Reporter for ClearCase", as part of "Development Intelligence" solution for ClearCase

Answer (score -1):

Here a useful snippet for Linux tcsh.

For each activity you get you may want to list its changed set.

You can use

`cleartool lsact -s` and `cleartool lsact -fmt "%[versions]p" <act_Name>`

as shown here:

**http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/961/list-files-changed-in-clearcase-ucm-stre?fromPage=1**