# clearcase ucm activity list between baselines

Tags: clearcase, cleartool, clearcase-ucm

How to get the list of the activities between two baselines in a file in clearcase ucm ?

Cleartool diffbl -lsact -pred latestlable >>activities.txt is the command used .

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to add `@\yourPVob`, as shown in [cleartool list activities since last 7 days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811879/cleartool-list-activities-since-last-7-days/3812471#3812471).

```
 cleartool diffbl -act -pred baseline:latestlable@\yourPVob
```

Note: on Unix, this would be `@/vobs/yourPVob`.
It is best to use the baseline selector syntax (see [`diffbl` man](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_diffbl.htm)):

> baseline-selector is of the form: `[baseline:]baseline-name[@vob-selector]` and vob is the baseline's UCM project VOB.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in python found on [snip2code.com](http://www.snip2code.com)

```
import os

bl_old="myOldBaseline@/MyVobs"
bl_new="myNewBaseline@/MyVobs"
myView = "MyView"

diff_act=os.popen("cleartool setview -exec \"cleartool diffbl -nmerge -activities "+bl_old+" "+ bl_new+" \" " +myView).readlines()

for act in diff_act:
   print ("ACTIVITY: "+str(act))
```

Link: [How To Get The List Of All The Activities Comparing UCM baselines](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/11389)