# ClearCase: how to list all the delivery activities between 2 baselines?

Tags: clearcase, release-management, clearcase-ucm

I want to list all activities in which we worked between two baselines. The baselines are in the same stream, but each developer is working in his own child stream and delivering their work. There are two [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811879/cleartool-list-activities-since-last-7-days/3812471#3812471) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257060/clearcase-ucm-activity-list-between-baselines)  in SO, but they don't list everything inside each activity.

In the GUI, I have to enter in each delivery activity and list activities that compound it.

Bonus points if you can list the activities between the most recent baseline and the predecessor that is in a specific promotion level.

Even more bonus poins if you can format the list to show just the activity name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the command to display the activities inside a **delivery** activity:

```
cleartool lsactivity -contrib activity_id@\yourPVob
```

BTW, maybe this will help somebody. You can list all the activities between two baselines (just activities outside a delivery activity):

```
cleartool diffbl -activities  baseline:baseline_before_id@\yourPVob  baseline:baseline_later_id@\yourPVob
```

And list all your baselines of PRODUCTION level (get the two latest to list the activities in your most recent release):

```
cleartool lsbl -component your_copmponent@\yourPVob  -stream your_integration_stream@\yourPVob  -level PRODUCTION-short'
```

Now you just need to do a simple recursion to get all activities between two baselines.

Comment: Good feedback on the `diffbl` and `lsbl` usage. +1

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find at first any built-in easy way to list activities involved in a deliver activity.

[This technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21118911) illustrates that the description of a deliver activity is only for listing *versions* created by the deliver, not activities delivered.

```
 cleartool describe -l activity:<deliver activity>@\<PVOB-tag>
```

Comment: I will check tomorrow at work if there is any link between the deliver activity and those activities delivered.