# ClearCase: how to list the text all the commit messages?

Tags: clearcase

I believe this is a simple question: I want to find which files were modified when I fixed a bug. I know some words in the commit messages. In other version control I'd list all the commit messages and grep for my correction. Something like:

```
svn log|grep -C 10 'Access Violation'
```

I can't find in ClearCase how to do the simple task of listing all the commit messages of a stream. I want to see also the commit messages of the child streams. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because there is no "commit message" per se in ClearCase.

- each file can have its own comment when checked-in
- the UCM activity in which you are checking in a file has its own comment
- the UCM baseline which will include several activities has its own comment.

So, for instance you can [list activities](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812471/6309) (as I illustrate in "[how to find the list activities delivered to integration stream on a particular day?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8732330/6309)"):

```
cleartool lsact -r -in stream:aStream@\aPVob -fmt "%n %c"|grep "Access Violation"
```

and grep on their comment message, using the [`fmt_ccase` format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm) to display the associated comment (with `%c`).

Note the `-r` (recursive) option, which will include activities from the child streams.