# Clearcase: List all comments messages in stream

Tags: clearcase

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004070/clearcase-how-to-list-the-text-all-the-commit-messages?lq=1) and run the below command :

> cleartool lsact -r -in stream:aStream@\aPVob -fmt "%n %c"

After running this I got :

> SOLNSxxxx Created automatically as a result of 'Work on' action in ClearQuest

I didn't get this as I am expecting the comment message against every activity and files checked-in in activity with commit message.

And will this change anything in clearquest too ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

> as I am expecting the comment message against every activity and files checked-in in activity with commit message.

No, that would return the name and comment of the activity only, not of its change set versions.

See "[How to find files associated with a ClearCase UCM activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10632818/6309)": for each version return, you would need to apply a `cleartool descr -fmt "%n %c"`

Try (not tested)

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%[versions]CQp"  activity-title@\aPVob |\
  xargs cleartool descr -fmt "%n %c"
```

If the first describe list all versions on one line, use:

```
cleartool describe -fmt "%versionsCp\n" activity:<your activity>@<your pVOB> | perl -pe 's/\,\s?/\n/g' 
# or
cleartool describe -fmt "%[versions]CQp\n" activity:<your activity>@<your pVOB> | perl -pe 's/\,\s?/\n/g'
```